# AngularJS Promise Response Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, response, angular-promise

I've read multiple articles on using `$promise` in AngularJS and I still can't figure out why I'm getting an error with my code below:

**CONTROLLER CODE:**

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope, eventData) {
        $scope.sortOrder = 'name';
        eventData.getEvent().$promise.then(successOnGetEvent(event), errorOnGetEvent(response));

        function successOnGetEvent(event) {
            $scope.event = event;
            console.log(event);
        };

        function errorOnGetEvent(response) {
            console.log(response)
        };
    });
```

**SERVICE CODE:**

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource) {
    return {
        getEvent: function() {
            return $resource('/data/event/:id', {id:'@id'}).get({id:1});
        }
    }
});
```

In the Chrome console window, I get the error:

> ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: What does the `eventData` service look like?

Comment: Updated Q with Service Code. Thanks

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, the `eventData` code wasn't required to spot the error here. My bad for not getting my coffee this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line...

```
eventData.getEvent().$promise.then(successOnGetEvent(event), errorOnGetEvent(response));
```

`successOnGetEvent` and `errorOnGetEvent` are being executed right away. The error is because `response` (and `event`) aren't declared in this context. Try just passing the functions instead...

```
eventData.getEvent().$promise.then(successOnGetEvent, errorOnGetEvent);
```

Comment: That worked, but can you please explain a bit more. If I do `function(event) { $scope.event = event; }` instead of my `successOnGetEvent(event)` it will work. Why does moving it outside into a named function (not anonymous function) breaks it? :/

Comment: If either of the handler-function relies on `this` then they won't work if you do it like that. Not an issue with the code in this question but worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @Ciwan `function(event) { .. }` is a function declaration while `successOnGetEvent(event)` is a function invocation.

Comment: If you use pass `successOnGetEvent(event)` to `then`, you're invoking `successOnGetEvent` with an argument of `event` then passing its return value to `then`. Leave out the `(event)` to pass the function.

Comment: Thanks @ivarni that made it clear. But I have a follow up Q. How does JavaScript know to pass the event parameter to my declared anonymous function?

Comment: It's not JavaScript that does that, what happens is that the anonymous function is passed by reference to `$promise.then` and it's now that code's responsibility to make sure the `event` argument is passed when the function is evenutally invoked. In your case this is handled by angular-resource since your `getEvent()` function is returning the result of calling the `$resource()` function. If you've got a background from a programming language that does not have first class functions then all of this is going to take some time getting used to.

Comment: I always struggle with this in JavaScript. I'm use to C# and Java style methods / functions. Any good resources on understanding this?

Answer (score 2):

You are actually passing the return value of your functions to the `promise.then`. you should pass a function. try this:

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope, eventData) {
        $scope.sortOrder = 'name';
        eventData.getEvent().$promise.then(function (event) { successOnGetEvent(event); }, function (response) { errorOnGetEvent(response); });

        function successOnGetEvent(event) {
            $scope.event = event;
            console.log(event);
        };

        function errorOnGetEvent(response) {
            console.log(response)
        };
});
```

What I did this is just add a wrapper anonymous function that runs the code you intended to run. This means the `promise.then` will receive a function.